# Переадресация NGINX

Tags: javascript, nginx, xmlhttprequest

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно переадресовать GET запрос отправленный как конкретный адрес, на конкретный IP адрес?
Например, в xmlhttprequest запрос отправляется на адрес mysite.com/1 - в этом случае переадресация должна быть на http://5.63.182.161:8001/?param=1. А если запрос направлен на mysite.com/0 - переадресация должна быть на http://5.63.182.161:8001/?param=0.

Comment: тебе в ответ должна прийти переадресация (301/302 статус) или тебе нужно проксирование ответа с 5.63.182.161:8001?

Comment: по предыдущему твоему вопросу становится понятно, что тебе нужно проксирование. читай http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html и http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html